# Splunk python SDK exporting json string

Tags: python, splunk

I'm trying to export query results from Splunk into a Python application. I've got Key-Value fields, and one of those has a json string (that is a json structure wrapped in quotes).

First I had encountered an issue where using the `table` command would only return the opening bracket (e.g. "{") - which I then resolved by extracting the text via `rex`.

However, despite the query working well in Splunk UI, including the download option, whenever I query via the SDK I keep getting "{" as a value.
I've tried CSV/JSON/XML exports, and all experience the same issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was an escaping one - I originally had:

```
| rex field=_raw ".*filter=(?<filter>\".*\}\"),"
```

Which when replaced with the following, worked:

```
| rex field=_raw ".*filter=(?<filter>\\".*\}\\"),"
```

Escaping had to be double in order to work properly.